# download mp3 file through xmlhttprequest and save it as a file somewhere for upload later

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am currently writing a chrome extension and am stuck at how to handle xmlhttprequest's responsetext as a file. As the title said, I need to download the mp3 given a link and save it as a real physical file anywhere that I can access again in my extension. I can't seem to find information on how to save a file from javascript given the type is not simple text. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: you can't download mp3 files with javascript if they don't have "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" in the header.php is a solution.but as u create an extension u prolly can't use php. in case they have "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" in the header i post u the code how to save your file.

Comment: @cocco I think I do have access control allow origin because the url to the mp3 is the same origin to which my extension is running on. I can make the xmlhttprequest from my extension, I just don't know how to save it as a file and that I can access again in my extension. Please post your code, it would help nevertheless, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

thi is the function that loads and mp3 in your case using xhr , covertsit to base64 an then executes a function with the base64 file string

```
var xhrfile=function(i,f){
 var c=new XMLHttpRequest();
 c.open('GET',i);
 c.responseType='arraybuffer';
 //c.onprogress=function(e){var perc=Math.round((e.loaded/e.total)*100)+' of 100'};
 c.onload=function(e){
  var u8=new Uint8Array(this.response),ic=u8.length,bs=[];
  while(ic--){bs[ic]=String.fromCharCode(u8[ic]);};
  f('data:audio/mpeg;base64,'+btoa(bs.join('')));
 };
 c.send();
}
```

usage:

```
 xhrfile('http://domain.com/your.mp3',filefunc)
```

now as you want to save the file use indexedDB,websql,localstorage,fileApi or whatever you want.... it's a string now.

consider that this mentioned saving possibilities have filesize limitations.

you can also simply output the file to download:

```
var filefunc=function(mp3data){
 var a=document.createElement('a');
 a.download='mp3name.mp3';
 a.href=mp3data;
 a.innerText='download the file';
 document.body.appendChild(a);
}
```

i don't tested this function with mp3... i know that it works on images and other small files.maybe start with a small mp3 file.

here is the blob version.

```
var xhrfile=function(i,f){
 var c=new XMLHttpRequest();
 c.open('GET',i);
 c.responseType='arraybuffer';
 c.onload=function(e){
  var blob = new Blob([this.response]);
  f(blob);
 };
 c.send();
}
```

blob to object url:

```
var objurl=window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

free memory

```
window.URL.revokeObjectURL(objurl);
```

Comment: Can I now use the callback for upload? Skydrive requires a link to the file, is this string a valid one for uploading?

Comment: i don't know what Skydrive is

Comment: can i construct a blob with this string? it would be easier for me to save it as a file if i can make it a blob.